# How to use special characters on pentaho Dashboard

Tags: pentaho, dashboard, utf, pentaho-cde, pentaho-ctools

I'm trying to use special characters on my dashboard using a HTML structure.

It only works if I use [HTML Entities](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html) such as "**& atilde;**" (without space) for **ã**.

But is it the only way to do it? Is there anywhere I can set UTF-8, for example?

I tried to put a META tag setting UTF-8, but I didn't work.

Here's what I'm doying:

Input:
[image]

Output:
[image]

I need to type: "Alocação de Funcionários"

Notice that I also set a custom noDataMessage_text on Advanced Properties > Extension points of my first Bar Char and, since the message also have special characters on it, using the HTML Entity would certainly not be a good idea.

**UPDATE:**

I have the same problem when I was looking for my Cubes when I was using the OLAP Selector Wizard

[image: OLAP Selector Wizard]

Comment: Did you try something like \u00E7 for your "ç"?

Comment: @bhericher, I tried the HTML Entities such as "&atilde;" and it works, but your HTML code gets visually bad.

A Unicode number - such as \u00E7 - does not work on the HTML structure, unless I have to do something else other than just put it there.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem will solve. You can use like these.

```
  <h1 style="font-weight: bold;"> Aloca&#231;&#227;o de Funcion&#225;rios<h1>
```

or

```
<h1 style="color:#297385l"> Aloca&Ccedil;&atilde;o de Funcion&aacute;rios</h1>
```

I got these output in my dashboard.

[image]

I am thinking your font family is creating some issue. Please copy the exact h1 tag line and paste it in your dashboard let's see.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much @Venkatesh Panabaka, but I already tried this, as I posted on bhericher's comment and it works indeed.

But it looks strange and it still don't solve all my problems, e.g. my custom noDataMessage_text.